# riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx2'

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite, riscv

I am trying to compile a Tensorflow lite code by using the riscv toolchain. My target is RISC-V [CVA6](https://github.com/openhwgroup/cva6) core. I use the [minimal example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal) as the starting point.

I see the errors are related to the vector extension. The CVA6 core only supports I, M, A, and C extension. Does anyone know how to get around this issue or how to disable the V extension?

Thank you

Here are the steps:

```
mkdir minimal_build
cd minimal_build
RISCVCC_PREFIX=$HOME/toolchains/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}g++ -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF ../tensorflow/lite/
cmake --build . -j
```

However, it gives me errors like below.

```
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx2'
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx512f'
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfma'
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/CMakeFiles/ruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target '_deps/ruy-build/ruy/CMakeFiles/ruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.dir/have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [_deps/ruy-build/ruy/CMakeFiles/ruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.dir/have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.cc.o] Error 1
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx512vl'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5423: recipe for target '_deps/ruy-build/ruy/CMakeFiles/ruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [_deps/ruy-build/ruy/CMakeFiles/ruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.dir/all] Error 2
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx512cd'
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx512bw'
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx512dq'
```

Comment: Those are completely alien options avx-something etc. are for Intel. So your toolchain is configured for the wrong architecture/has missed the fact that you are cross-compiling.

Comment: that's weird... because I've used this toolchain to compile simple C/C++ programs and they run fine on the CVA6 core. I am trying to build a new toolchain. Do you have any suggestions how to configure the toolchain? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure the toolchain (as in gcc) is perfectly fine. It's probably cmake that is confused. What arguments are you using for cmake? https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm <- the incantations for arm could provide a hint.

Comment: Ah, you did put those in the question. My bad. Anyway, you're probably missing a `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` environment var. Which should point to a file in your toolchain that looks something like [this example](https://github.com/openxla/iree/blob/main/build_tools/cmake/riscv.toolchain.cmake).

Comment: Thanks! I checked this webpage tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm to get some ideas. I added new CC flag like this but it seems like the issue is still there. 
RISCV_CC_FLAGS="-funsafe-math-optimizations"

Comment: You probably need at least `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=riscv` to make cmake stop thinking you're on Intel.

Comment: I couldn't locate a file in the toolchain looks like this riscv.toolchain.cmake file for `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`. Do you think it's something I should create myself?

Comment: Adding `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=rv64`  and `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux` works! Thank you so much for the help @teapot418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from @teapot418
The below steps work

```
mkdir minimal_build
cd minimal_build

RISCVCC_PREFIX=$HOME/toolchains/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-
RISCV_CC_FLAGS="-funsafe-math-optimizations"

cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}gcc \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}g++ \
  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${RISCV_CC_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${RISCV_CC_FLAGS}" \
  -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=rv64 \
  ../tensorflow/lite

cmake --build . -j
```